# Bluetooth App crashes on launch

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am an absolute beginner in android development. I tried making a Bluetooth app
 and it crashes on launch. The app is supposed to search and connect to a specific device whose name is entered by the user. I've caught every exception but I am clueless. Any help would be appreciated. The Complete code is attached.
Thanks.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
UUID newUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
InputStream inStream;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices = new ArrayList<>();
public TextView text = findViewById(R.id.textView);
public String incomingMessage;
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch (state) {
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    Log.d("", "onReceive: STATE OFF");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                    Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING OFF");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                    Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE ON");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                    Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING ON");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {

            int mode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch (mode) {
                //Device is in Discoverable Mode
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:
                    Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Enabled.");
                    break;
                //Device not in discoverable mode
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:
                    Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Able to receive connections.");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                    Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Not able to receive connections.");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connecting....");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connected.");
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
};
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d("", "onReceive: ACTION FOUND.");

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            devices.add(device);
            Log.d("", "onReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());
        }

    }
};
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver4 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                Log.d("", "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDED.");
            }
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                Log.d("", "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDING.");
            }
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                Log.d("", "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_NONE.");
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onCLick(View button) {
    IntentFilter m4 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4,m4);
    if(adapter==null)
    {
        Log.d("","Bluetooth is null");
        onDestroy();
    }
    EditText deviceName = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String name = deviceName.getText().toString();
    BluetoothDevice targetDevice = null;
    if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, 1);

        IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1,BTIntent);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BT TURNED ON",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2,intentFilter);

    }
    Set<BluetoothDevice> paired_devices = adapter.getBondedDevices();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GETTING BONDED DEVICES",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (paired_devices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice mdevice : paired_devices) {
            if (mdevice.getName().equals("name")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"FOUND DEVICE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                targetDevice = mdevice;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SEARCHING DEVICES",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(adapter.isDiscovering())
            adapter.cancelDiscovery();
        adapter.startDiscovery();
        IntentFilter deviceFound = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3,deviceFound);
        for(BluetoothDevice mdevice:devices)
        {
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(mdevice.getName()))
            {
                targetDevice = mdevice;
            }
        }
        if(devices.size()==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO DEVICE FOUND... QUITTING",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    BluetoothSocket mSocket = null;
    try {
        assert targetDevice != null;
        mSocket = targetDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(newUUID);
    } catch (IOException | AssertionError e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"COULD NOT BE CONNECTED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        assert mSocket != null;
        mSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException|AssertionError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"COULD NOT MAKE CONNECTION",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        assert mSocket != null;
        inStream = mSocket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException|AssertionError | NullPointerException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"PROBLEM CONNECTING",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            int bytes = inStream.read(buffer);
             incomingMessage = new String(buffer,0,bytes);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
    text.setText(incomingMessage);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"END OF PROGRAM",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v3qI.png]
[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Ge5.png ]

Second link for logcat crash after button press

Comment: Post your crash logcat.

Comment: There is a null point exception and am not able to figure out where 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view

Comment: What are you pasting. That's not enough. Either paste full crash in your question by editing it again.

Comment: Added the logcat Picture through the link. 
Have a look at it

Comment: I am just curious, why `TextView text` is outside of `onCreate`?

Comment: Put `public TextView text = findViewById(R.id.textView);` in `onCreate` that should fix it.

Comment: @Michal_196 Textview text was before onCreate so that it could be declared public and both methods onClick and onCreate could see it. 
Puttinig text feild in onCreate inhibits onClick seeing it

Comment: Ok, so declare `TextView text` outside of `onCreate`, and initialize it in `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

You can not find a view by id, until it is rendered. If you write `findViewById` at global level, then activity tries to load that View before setting layout.

Put your `findViewById` code after `setContentView()`.

```
package in.ks.widgetClock.defaultClasses.webservice;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import in.ks.widgetClock.R;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    UUID newUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
    InputStream inStream;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices = new ArrayList<>();
    public TextView text;

    public String incomingMessage;
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch (state) {
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        Log.d("", "onReceive: STATE OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE ON");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING ON");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {

                int mode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch (mode) {
                    //Device is in Discoverable Mode
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:
                        Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Enabled.");
                        break;
                    //Device not in discoverable mode
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:
                        Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Able to receive connections.");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                        Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Not able to receive connections.");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connecting....");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        Log.d("", "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connected.");
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    };
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d("", "onReceive: ACTION FOUND.");

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                devices.add(device);
                Log.d("", "onReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());
            }

        }
    };
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver4 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    Log.d("", "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDED.");
                }
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    Log.d("", "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDING.");
                }
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                    Log.d("", "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_NONE.");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public void onCLick(View button) {
        IntentFilter m4 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4,m4);
        if(adapter==null)
        {
            Log.d("","Bluetooth is null");
            onDestroy();
        }
        EditText deviceName = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String name = deviceName.getText().toString();
        BluetoothDevice targetDevice = null;
        if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, 1);

            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1,BTIntent);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BT TURNED ON",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
            startActivity(discoverableIntent);

            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2,intentFilter);

        }
        Set<BluetoothDevice> paired_devices = adapter.getBondedDevices();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GETTING BONDED DEVICES",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (paired_devices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice mdevice : paired_devices) {
                if (mdevice.getName().equals("name")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"FOUND DEVICE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    targetDevice = mdevice;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SEARCHING DEVICES",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(adapter.isDiscovering())
                adapter.cancelDiscovery();
            adapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter deviceFound = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3,deviceFound);
            for(BluetoothDevice mdevice:devices)
            {
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(mdevice.getName()))
                {
                    targetDevice = mdevice;
                }
            }
            if(devices.size()==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO DEVICE FOUND... QUITTING",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        BluetoothSocket mSocket = null;
        try {
            assert targetDevice != null;
            mSocket = targetDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(newUUID);
        } catch (IOException | AssertionError e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"COULD NOT BE CONNECTED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            assert mSocket != null;
            mSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException|AssertionError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"COULD NOT MAKE CONNECTION",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try {
            assert mSocket != null;
            inStream = mSocket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException|AssertionError | NullPointerException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"PROBLEM CONNECTING",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(true)
        {
            try {
                int bytes = inStream.read(buffer);
                incomingMessage = new String(buffer,0,bytes);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
        text.setText(incomingMessage);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"END OF PROGRAM",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Khemraj, the app does not crash in opening now but crashes on clicking on the button, any idea why ?

Comment: Again i would say, post your logcat. So that i can identify issue.

Comment: Sorry completely forgot that 
Shared the logcat . Have a look

Comment: onCLick , see this in your xml layout, it should be same.

Comment: one interesting thing i noticed was that it would ask permission for switching on the bluetooth after the crash.. Do you know why so ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is dedicated to resolve issues. If you want make review your code. Visit https://codereview.stackexchange.com/